# EOFError: Bad Content Body in API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

There's a few other stack posts around similar errors, though the trace of mine highlights different method failures and typically these errors occur in multipart forms, which mine is not. I've been looking at this problem on and off for a few weeks now and decided it was time to ask others for help.

The scenario: I have an API mounted engine which I built. It's lightweight, has a controller and a method to receive post requests with data logs. These logs are often 60,000~ bytes in size and are accessed through `request.body.read`. To make sure it wasn't an error provoked by my code. I removed everything, it's literally an empty method that just returns 200 now. Like this:

```
def tcpdata
  return 200
end
```

Yet, I still get the error. Which makes it really frustrating because it seems out of my hands.

The error I get is `ERROR EOFError: bad content body` and it's failing in the rack multipart method `get_current_head_and_filename_and_content_type_and_name_and_body`

Here's the full trace:

```
2016-07-16T12:31:06.624089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/endpoint/devices" host=getbeambox.com request_id=992b3308-97db-4dbe-9ab0-343ee0a4f49f fwd="79.77.176.13,141.101.99.214" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=309ms status=500 bytes=507
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627426+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-07-16 12:31:06] ERROR EOFError: bad content body
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627448+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:148:in `get_current_head_and_filename_and_content_type_and_name_and_body'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627450+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:59:in `block in parse'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627451+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:56:in `loop'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627452+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:56:in `parse'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627452+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/multipart.rb:25:in `parse_multipart'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627453+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/request.rb:375:in `parse_multipart'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627454+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/request.rb:207:in `POST'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627454+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:39:in `method_override_param'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627455+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:27:in `method_override'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627456+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:15:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627457+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627458+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627459+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627459+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627460+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627461+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627463+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627463+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627464+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627465+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627466+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627466+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627467+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627468+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627469+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627469+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2016-07-16T12:31:06.627470+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Worth noting I'm on rack 1.6.4 - Doing an upgrade to 2.0.1 now.

Comment: Can you log your content body?

Answer (score 0):

For me Postman was creating problem when I had selected form-data in the BODY tab. When I changed it to raw it worked for me.

I have seen this error in multipart forms.